# Выход (logout) пользователя после добавления записи в БД и загрузки файлов на сервер

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Сообщения об ошибке нет. - только 404 по заданному маршруту. `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />` установлен.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным авто логаутом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Были сгенерированы MachineKey в IIS и помещены в web.config в секцию:

```
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" />
    <machineKey decryptionKey="***" validationKey="***"/>
```

Собственно причина была в том, что приложение было сконфигурировано так, что ключи "генерируются на лету", что, как замечено, практически всегда приводит к вылетанию сессий пользователя в .net приложениях.

Разовая генерация ключей и жесткое прописывание ключей в конфиге решает данную проблему.

P.S. проблема была решена хостером за 10 мин, респект parking.ru, а упущение моё.